# JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'prop'

Tags: javascript, jquery

My script is failing in calling `prop()`. I am getting the message:

> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'prop'

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
            return;
        }
        var checkvalue = $(this).val();
        $('input:hidden[id*="_PropositieType"]').val(checkvalue);
        $("input:checkbox").not(this).removeAttr("checked");
    });
});
```

I am using IE 11 and jquery 1.5.1. I want it to work with all browsers.

Comment: Don't use `click`, use `change` event

Comment: what jquery version you are using ?

Comment: isn't the default behaviour suppose to do what you are trying to do?

Comment: ... and what is the sense of this? If you want your checkboxes to be always checked, you can just check them and disable user interaction by adding `disabled`

Comment: Anyway any jQuery code should be included in `$(document).ready(function() {...});` or it could not execute correctly

Comment: Do a `console.log` in your event and see if it is executing? If it is not try to warp you codes in `$(function() {});` block.

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but I think `.prop` was not in jQuery as of version 1.5

Comment: `jquery 1.5.1` that's said it all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use j Query 1.6 or higher version

j Query 1.6+ uses

```
$('.Checkbox').prop('checked', true);
$('.Checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```

jQuery 1.5. and below

```
$('.Checkbox').attr('checked', true);
$('.Checkbox').attr('checked', false);
```

Comment: Thanks @Anurag Deokar

Answer (score 2):

Try `attr` in place of `prop`. Because `prop` is available in jQuery version 1.6+.

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) you can find the complete info.